# Rails "Getting Started" guide link_to NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I'm following the Rails "Getting Started" guide (in which you make a blog website), and have reached step 5.8. At this point, you are displaying all the articles written so far, in a tabular format. Next to each article there is meant to be a link to the full article itself:

```
<h1>Listing articles</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Whenever I try and access http://localhost:3000/articles, I get a NameError in Articles#index, saying:

undefined local variable or method `“Show”' for #<#:0x00007fb69bb18e98>

The articles_controller is as follows:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @articles = Article.all
        end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        end

    def new
        end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
        end

    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
            end

end
```

Any other link_to operations given in the guide don't seem to be working either and I can't figure out why. Any help would be massively appreciated!

EDIT: Here's what I get in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-02 22:30:21 +0000
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Rendering articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (322.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 351ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `“Show”' for #<#<Class:0x00007faa22ae61a8>:0x00007faa22acf430>):
    10:         <tr>
    11:         <td><%= article.title %></td>
    12:         <td><%= article.text %></td>
    13:         <td><%= link_to “Show”, article_path(article) %></td>
    14:         </tr>
    15:     <% end %>
    16: </table>

app/views/articles/index.html.erb:13:in `block in _app_views_articles_index_html_erb___2950076423591311193_70184351523660'
app/views/articles/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_articles_index_html_erb___2950076423591311193_70184351523660'
```

Comment: What's the full error you get?

Comment: I've edited my post to contain the terminal output!

Comment: Replace `“”` for double quotes `""`.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!!

Comment: Note you can only use single and/or double quotes - depending on what you're trying to do. Left/right quotation marks aren't valid for working with strings.

Comment: I had no clue, really appreciate the help!